# How to interpret a linear regression model of logged numeric variables

Tags: r, regression, linear

Below is my model. All numeric variables have been transformed by the natural log (dependent and independent). I am wanting to understand how I can interpret my results. Is it correct to say the following?

Every one unit increase of logged variable `AmountSpent` increases logged variable `Revenue` by .06 units on average holding all other variables constant.

Every 1% increase of `AmountSpent` increases `Revenue` by .06% on average holding all other variables constant.

`AdFormatGIF` makes .14 units more of logged variable `Revenue` than the reference level `AdFormatIMG` on average holding all other variables constant.

```
Call:

lm(formula = Revenue ~ AmountSpent + AdFormat, data = Ads6)

Residuals:

   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 

-4.112 -0.470 -0.067  0.432  5.369 

Coefficients:

                Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    

(Intercept)     3.9073         0.0647       60.43       < 0.0000000000000002 ***    
AmountSpent     0.0646        0.0220       2.94                0.00330 ** 
AdFormatGIF     0.1441        0.0376       3.83                 0.00013 ***    
AdFormatVID     0.1152        0.0383      3.01                0.00266 **     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.837 on 3023 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.817, Adjusted R-squared:  0.817 
F-statistic: 1.69e+03 on 8 and 3023 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but related to your question: It is usually advisable (and statistically more sound) to use a generalised linear model (GLM) with a log link function, instead of log-transforming your response (dependent) variable within an OLS linear model. In other words you want to be transforming your (unknown) population parameter (the mean in this case) instead of your observed data. The reason for this is that log-transforming your response may change the data's underlying probability distribution and its properties.

Comment: At least for count data, it is *always* a bad idea to log-transform your data (see e.g. [O'Hara, Do not log-transform count data](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00021.x)). More generally, a GLM with a log-link is *always* preferred over log-transforming data for your *dependent variable* and then using a simple (i.e. linear link) LM.

Comment: @MauritsEvers $y_i=ax_i^b\varepsilon_i$ can of course be a valid model for some data out there.

Comment: @Roland Models like [$y_i = (a + b x_i)\epsilon_i$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107704/multiplicative-errors-for-linear-model) are just ordinary linear models with heteroskedasticity. To quote from that link: *"To estimate this model, you would just run OLS and use heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors."* That post also suggests that such models are rarely used in practice, and instead are more of an educational exercise. I certainly have never used them in my line of work.